# Ok to include a 'T' in MySQL date time sting?

Tags: mysql, datetime, concatenation

The MySQL manual specifies the datetime to be formatted:

```
'2011-10-02 16:04:32'  /* YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS */
```

But MySQL 5.1 also accepts the [ISO 8601 combined date and time format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601):

```
'2011-10-02T16:04:32' /* YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS */
```

I often concatenate a date and time together to make a MySQL datetime datatype, and I worry the space does not look important enough in the concattenation code.

```
$newdate = $datepart . ' ' . $timepart;
```

What if someone confuses it for an empty string someday and deletes the space, breaking the application?  This looks better to me:

```
$newdate = $datepart . 'T' . $timepart;
```

Will MySQL continue to support the ISO 8601 format with the 'T'?

Am I violating a best practice by doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Will MySQL continue to support the ISO 8601 format with the 'T'?**

Probably, I can't think of a reason why they would stop. There's also tons of libraries which handle timestamp parsing which would easily lend you a workaround if they randomly did stop.

**Am I violating a best practice by doing this?**

Not particularly, it's more of a preference than anything else.

Comment: I don't think I would need a library to add or remove a 'T'.  The main point of my question is to ask if there is a best practice for MySQL.